# How do I remove core search index?

Tags: search

I want to remove the core search index. In Drupal 7 I achieved this by adding the following line to the settings.php file.

```
$conf['search_cron_limit'] = '0';
```

What is the equivalent for Drupal 8?

Comment: Normally you uninstall the core search module and install [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) to configure another backend like Solr. Using core search without the built-in index seems very unusual to me. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @4k4 I’ve seen people do that when they have a set of search results that they consider perfect and don’t want anything to change. They still want search functionality they just want the index to be a snapshot of a point in time. It’s definitely unusual but not unheard of

Comment: @Clive, yes, this would be a valid reason to stop the cron search. I understood the question like this [D7 question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44558/how-to-remove-core-search-index) to remove the index from the database. In this case it's very likely you want to use Search API where the whole search ecosystem is now, see https://www.drupal.org/project/contrib_tracker/issues/2613470#comment-10584530

Comment: @4k4 ah right, I didn’t read it like that. Yeah if that’s what they’re asking search api is definitely the answer. Not even sure why core bothers including a search to be honest, it’s a large maintenance overhead for no real gain when you think how much more advanced the contrib module is